# Jquery - How to write parameter in selector

Tags: jquery

i have a function like this

```
var isCheck = function (x){
      var $x = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name$="x"]');
}
```

how can i use my parameter 'x' in the selector which is in the variable $x ??

Tnx.

NOTE : **('input[name$="x"]')** is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah i got it..

```
 var tdExpiryDate = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name$="' + txt2 + '"]');
```